# how to infer distribution (mean and SD) of a trait according to its value and type in R

Tags: r, distribution

I have a dataframe like this

```
id  anxiety_score  anxiety_diagnosis
1     0             nomal
2     0             normal
3     13            mild 
4     12            mild
5     15            mild
6     13            mild
7     7             normal
8     4             normal
9     16            severe
10    17            severe
11    21            severe
12    1             normal
```

people including three diagnosis of anxiety (normal, mild, severe) finished my anxiety scale, of which the score are showed in the column named "anxiety_score".  Now I want to infer the distribution (i.e. mean and SD)  of the score accoring to the diagnosis. It means that after I know the distribution of the scores, I can locate the participants, and the location match the diagnosis. How could I do that in R?

Comment: You should start by computing the mean and sd of score by each class of `anxiety_diagnosis`!

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(anxiety_diagnosis) %>% summarise(sd = sd(anxiety_score), mn = mean(anxiety_score))` ?

Comment: I would start with side by side boxplots. `boxplot(axiety_score ~ anxiety_diagnosis, ylab="Score", xlab="Diagnosis") ` and do histograms to look at the shape of the distribution and get a feel if means and standard deviations describe your population.  I would worry about floor and ceiling effects (seeing a limited range of scores) before you worry about the means and standard deviations.